# hide proof environment for restructuring

Tags: environments, amsthm, comments, draft

I am writing my thesis,

and i am in restructuring phase - sorting theorems where they should belong thematically. And it would be helpful to have all the proofs hidden so i am not laden with the additional information.

Is it possible to add something like `hideproof` to `documentclass` options to omit them when compiling the latex file.

Comment: Use the comment package, as discussed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106457/how-to-redefine-an-environment-to-produce-no-output

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can put this code to the very end of your preamble:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{killcontents}{}
\let\proof\killcontents
\let\endproof\endkillcontents
```

It defines the environment `killcontents` that kills its contents, and then "maps" `proof` environment to `killcontents`.

Comment: Won't just `\newenvironment{killcontents}{}{}` do, so you don't need the `environ` package? Also, I don't think there is a second `{}` for `\NewEnviron`

Comment: @PeterGrill No. Such environment would do nothing, i.e. leave its contents as is. And you are right, the second `{}` is a non-sense, edited.

Comment: Duhhh??? Don't know what came over me. Must have been a momentary lapse of reason.

Comment: It was very helpful for me. Great!