# How to redefine an environment to produce no output?

Tags: environments, verbatim, comments

I am using the `verbatim` environment with

```
\begin{verbatim}
XXXX
\end{verbatim}
```

I would like the option of redefining the verbatim environment so that nothing between `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` is printed. So I can print a long version of the paper with the verbatim information, and a short version with verbatim information omitted. I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to do this.

Comment: Related: [Commenting out large sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5764)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) allows you to (re)define comment environments. So, include the following in your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{comment}% http://ctan.org/pkg/comment
\excludecomment{verbatim}
```

which should *exclude* `verbatim` environment content from your document. If you want to include all the `verbatim` content again (for the longer version of your article, comment out the `\excludecomment{verbatim}` line.

For a more piece-meal approach to removing `verbatim` content, the following is possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}% http://ctan.org/pkg/comment
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\excludecomment{verbatim}
A
\begin{verbatim}
&^_%\{}
\end{verbatim}
B
\endgroup

A
\begin{verbatim}
&^_%\{}
\end{verbatim}
B

\end{document}
```

Another mild alternative to `comment` would be to gobble the environment contents using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). The following is not heavily tested, but works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\voidenvironment}[1]{%
  \expandafter\providecommand\csname env@#1@save@env\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\providecommand\csname env@#1@process\endcsname{}%
  \@ifundefined{#1}{}{\RenewEnviron{#1}{}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\voidenvironment{verbatim}%
A
\begin{verbatim}
&^_%\{}
\end{verbatim}
B
\endgroup

A
\begin{verbatim}
&^_%\{}
\end{verbatim}
B

\end{document}
```

Note the difference in output. After `verbatim` is gobbled, there's technically only a line-break (space) between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Excellent @Werner! This seems to work nicely and I can use it to get rid of proofs as well.

Comment: The first part of the answer seem not to work with `beamer` document class even the `fragile` frame option is presented. Especially when working with `proof` environment `\excludecomment{proof}`

Comment: @SayOL: That's because [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) processes the `frame`s differently than one would think. You'll have to redefine `proof` using the [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ)-like approach for it to work properly in `beamer`.

Answer (score 4):

For the shorter version of your paper, you could load the `comment` package and replace all instances of `{verbatim}` with `{comment}`. That way, you won't have to deal with issues that arise from characters such as `&` and `#` occurring in the verbatim/comment areas.

Comment: Haha.You beat me by 16 seconds!

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to work fine.  Would it be possible for me to redefine the verbatim environment to be the comment environment?  Then I would only to have to do that once at the beginning of the file instead of replacing every instance.

Comment: @WAJ I think it's not possible due to the "voodoo" that `verbatim` does; but perhaps someone will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I come long after the battle but here is a way which just imitates the way `verbatim` is done in `source2e`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\let\original@proof\proof

% Plagiarizing verbatim set-up:
\begingroup 
    \catcode `|=0 \catcode `[= 1 \catcode`]=2 
    \catcode `\{=12 \catcode `\}=12 \catcode`\\=12 
    |long|gdef|suppressed@proof #1\end{proof}[|end[proof]]
|endgroup
\def\makeproofsinvisible
  {\def\proof
      {\catcode`\{=12 \catcode `\}=12 \catcode`\\=12 \suppressed@proof }}
\def\makeproofsvisible{\let\proof\original@proof }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[Unkn.]
  Dog exists.
\end{theo}

\begin{proof}
  First step: actually, we don't really exist.
\end{proof}

\makeproofsinvisible

\begin{proof}
  Second step is censored.
\end{proof}

\makeproofsvisible

\begin{proof}
  Third Step: hence Dog exists.
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

[image: invisible proofs]

Comment: The reason this answer deals with the `proof` environment is that I was working on this [other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114465/how-to-ignore-proofs) when it got closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is from mine  previous similar question [Comment out lines without using % and comment enviroment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79522/comment-out-lines-without-using-and-comment-enviroment) which was answered by @egreg.

Seems to working properly with `\begin{equation}....`
 But unfortunately it does not work well with `\begin{verbatim}...`

However, it is a good idea if finally corrected the bug. It will generally useful in the future

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifprolog
\long\def\startprolog#1\stopprolog{%
  \ifprolog
  \par
  \begingroup
  \let\\\par
   #1 
  \par\medskip
  \endgroup
  \fi}

\prologtrue % comment out for omitted the inside \startprolog \stopprolog content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\startprolog
\begin{equation}
 k = \frac{1}{2} m u^2
\end{equation}
\stopprolog

\lipsum[1]

\startprolog
\begin{verbatim}
> eqn:=diff(y(t),t,t)+4*y(t)=0:
> inits:=y(0)=1,D(y)(0)=-1:
> dsolve({eqn,inits},y(t));
\end{verbatim}
\stopprolog

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```