# Remove all proof environments

Tags: environments, amsthm

I have a document containing some proofs and want to create a version only containing the theorems (and corollaries and lemmas and examples and …), but no proofs at all.

Is there an easy, automatic way to do that?

Comment: Did you use the `proof` environment?

Comment: You can use [`comment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) package and `\excludecomment{proof}`.

Comment: use this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106457/how-to-redefine-an-environment-to-produce-no-output

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I do.

Comment: @Ignasi: Thanks, that seems to be very easy. :)

Answer (score 4):

I personally use the `versions` package for this kind of work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\usepackage{versions}
    \includeversion{prop}
    %\excludeversion{prop}
    \includeversion{dem}
    %\excludeversion{dem}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
    \begin{thm}
        \( (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2\).
    \end{thm}
\end{prop}
\begin{dem}
    \begin{proof}
        \( (a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b) = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \).
    \end{proof}
\end{dem}
\end{document}
```

Since I've commented here both `\excludeversion{prop}` and `\excludeversion{dem}` out, both `thm` and `proof` environments appear:

[image]

But if I choose to comment `\includeversion{dem}` and comment out `\excludeversion{dem}`, it makes the proof disappear.

```
\usepackage{versions}
    \includeversion{prop}
    %\excludeversion{prop}
    %\includeversion{dem}
    \excludeversion{dem}
```

[image]

The same will apply to all your `proof` environments if you've enclosed them in this `dem` environment defined by `versions`.

To the contrary, you can choose to make the `proof` environments stay and the `thm` environments vanish if you apply the same maneuver to those `thm` environment (enclosing them in the `prop` environment defined by `versions`, commenting in/out the adequate lines:

```
\usepackage{versions}
    %\includeversion{prop}
    \excludeversion{prop}
    \includeversion{dem}
    %\excludeversion{dem}
```

[image]

The wide variety of possibilities makes this solution most flexible.

Comment: Thanks, but does `version` have any advantages over `comment`?

Comment: Excerpt from the documentation:  `Included environments never form groups in
‘comment’, here user may choose whether they form groups or not, at least for simple
including (not with marks). ‘comment’ includes by writing on and reading from disk,
present package needs no writing on disk… ‘Comment’ sometimes produces wrong spaces and discovers
‘\end{comment}’ only if nothing else is in the input line.`

Comment: @fpast From your answer (and a quick test) I understand that we need to surround `proof` and `thm` environments with external environments (`prop` and `dem`) in order to be excluded or included through `versions` package. Is not possible to use `\excludeversion{thm}`?

Comment: @Ignasi Yes, it is possible to use `\excludeversion{thm}` with would result in the disappearance of every `thm` environments, but if you use `\includeversion{thm}` then only the contents of `thm` environments would be printed, without any feature coming from the `amsthm` package. For this reason, and at the cost of some more lines in my programs, I prefer surrounding the `thm` environment by another defined with `versions` (as `dem` here).

Comment: @fpast Understood. Thank you for this reference to `versions`. I didn't know it.