# Hide indented amsthm environment using comment package

Tags: environments, amsthm, comments

I use `amsthm` to define a "Solution" environment. I want to be able to hide it. Following [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230041/remove-all-proof-environments#comment543349_230041) I tried using the `comment` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{solution*}{Solution}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{solution*}

\begin{document}
Foo
  \begin{solution*}
    Bar
  \end{solution*}
Baz
\end{document}
```

However this doesn't work because my solution environment is indented and the comment package requires

> The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it.

So my question is: how can I hide an indented solution environment defined with amsthm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capture the `solution*` environment contents using the powers provided by [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) and never display it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{solution*}{Solution}
%\usepackage{comment}
%\excludecomment{solution*}

\usepackage{environ}
\RenewEnviron{solution*}{}% or \RenewEnviron{solution*}{\par}

\begin{document}
Foo
  \begin{solution*}
    Bar
  \end{solution*}
Baz
\end{document}
```

Depending on the application, you may want to issue `\par`, or something to the effect that may separate the contents above `solution*` from that below.