# How can I create a show/hide button?

Tags: pdf, interaction

I would like to create a show/hide button that appears on a typeset PDF so that when it is clicked, the content appears.
This is similar to the ideas here: [Hide all but one instances of a custom environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141590/hide-all-but-one-instances-of-a-custom-environment?lq=1) and here: [hide proof environment for restructuring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45624/hide-proof-environment-for-restructuring/45627#45627), but I would like the option to show up in the PDF itself as a simple button that could be clicked (or something similar)
Ideally, this would end up looking something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{showhide}[1]{Does what I am describing}

\begin{document}

\showhide{Displays a button, that when clicked, shows this text
and when clicked again, hides this text.}

\end{document}
```

Anyone know how do do this, or something similar?

Comment: Read documentation of [`ocgx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx). In the documents tree of your TeX distribution also a file `demo-ocgx.pdf` is included, try executing `texdoc demo-ocgx` on your command prompt. The according tex file is found in the source tree.

Comment: Or try the `\tooltip` macro from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186