# Expandable/collapsible paragraphs in the compiled PDF file

Tags: pdf

I'm using Gummi on Ubuntu 14.04. I like Gummi because it gives me a live preview as I type lots of maths equations. But this is besides the point.

**My question:** Is there a way to "attach" an expandable\collapsible `[+]` / `[-]` type button to a given paragraph so that when the button is clicked within the PDF the associated paragraph either appears or disappears?

When writing up my maths notes this would be a very useful feature as it would allow to either display or hide proofs. Sometimes, it's nice just to have the results shown, without the proofs. On the other hand, it would be desirable to have the proofs to hand when required.

Please note I would like this functionality within the compiled PDF, not the actual tex code.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Martin Schröder in the comments [here is a similar question regarding ocgx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168770/how-can-i-create-a-show-hide-button).

Comment: I would guess that this functionality is mostly dependent on your choice of PDF viewer... there are a number of similar questions on this site dealing with advanced capabilities of PDF output, you may want to try looking around for them. In addition, I know that the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) manual contains somewhat similar features as you are asking about

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: I think you have two options: Either use OCGs or ECMAScript. Since neither is TeX-specific, I kindly suggest that you ask your question on [so] and then come back when you know _what_ must be changed in the PDF.

Comment: Regarding `ocgs`, I don't seem to find much online. I do however find `ocgx`, the demo PDF of which does not seem to provide what I'm looking for on the face of it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pbs Check the demo at http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/demo-ocgx.pdf, check slide 2, with the "Hide" and "Show" buttons.

Comment: @666 Thanks. I don't think it's what I'm after as I really want all text forward of a collapsed paragraph to appear directly after the expand/collapse button. The slide seems to suggest this does not happen. I will give it a whirl though ! c.f. a GUI tree view with expand/collapse `[+]/[-]`.